# SQL Select case to create new value

Tags: sql, select

Hello guys I am sorry but I didn’t know what I should call this question.

I have a table that contains information one these are how long it took from when the row was created and until it was last updated these are shown within the following columns:

```
CREATED
LAST_UPD
```

The time difference between these are shown in a separate column called:

```
SOLVED_SEC
```

(The time is shown in seconds)

Now I want to collect some of the data from this table but should the CREATED (which is a date) be outside of our company’s opening hours, the SOLVED_SEC should recalculated in my

Our opening hours exists in a table called KS_DRIFT.SYS_DATE_KS.

This table has a column named: THIS_DATE_OPENING.

I was thinking that I could calculate the new solved time as such:

```
THIS_DATE_OPENING-LAST_UPD
```

However I’m not quite sure how to do this

The following is the SQL that i have right now:

```
SELECT   
    TIDSPUNKT, LAST_UPD, AA.CREATED,
    TRUNC(AA.SOLVED_SEC/60/60,2) as LØST_TIME,
    //this is my attempt
    CASE 
        WHEN AA.CREATED >= CC.THIS_DATE_CLOSING 
          THEN LØST_TIME = (LAST_UPD-CC.THIS_DATE_OPENING) AS LØST_TIME 
    END,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN AA.LAST_UPD >= CC.THIS_DATE_CLOSING THEN 1 END) as AFTER_CLOSING,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='Færdig' THEN 1 END)as Completed_Callbacks
FROM     
    KS_DRIFT.NYK_SIEBEL_CALLBACK_AGENT_H_V AA 
INNER JOIN 
    KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO BB ON AA.TIDSPUNKT = BB.DATO 
RIGHT JOIN 
    KS_DRIFT.SYS_DATE_KS CC ON AA.TIDSPUNKT = CC.THIS_DATE
WHERE    
    AA.TIDSPUNKT BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2013-04-04'
    AND AA.AFSLUTTET_AF = BB.INITIALER
GROUP BY 
    AA.TIDSPUNKT, LØST_SEKUNDER, LAST_UPD, AA.CREATED
```

Sadly this doesn’t work.

My question is how can I change the value of SOLVED_SEC if the CREATED > THIS_DATE_CLOSED ?

Should you require additional information please do not hesitate to comment.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following:

```
CASE WHEN (AA.CREATED >= CC.THIS_DATE_CLOSING) THEN (AA.LAST_UPD-CC.THIS_DATE_OPENING) END AS SOVLED_AFTER_OPENING
```

However i get

```
"not a GROUP BY expression"
```

**UPDATE 2**

My SQL statement now looks like this:

```
    SELECT   TIDSPUNKT,
         AA.CREATED,
         LAST_UPD,
         AA.AGENTGRUPPE,
         TRUNC(AA.LØST_SEKUNDER/60/60,2) as LØST_TIME,
         'LØST_TIME' = CASE WHEN AA.CREATED >= CC.THIS_DATE_CLOSING THEN DATEDIFF(ss, CC.THIS_DATE_OPENING, LAST_UPD) END,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN AA.AGENTGRUPPE not in('Hovednumre','Privatcentre','Forsikring','Hotline','Stabe','Kunder','Erhverv','NykreditKunder','Servicecentret') THEN 1 END) as CALLBACKS_OUTSIDE_OF_KS,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN AA.CREATED >= CC.THIS_DATE_CLOSING THEN 1 END) as AFTER_CLOSING,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='Færdig' THEN 1 END)as Completed_Callbacks
FROM     KS_DRIFT.NYK_SIEBEL_CALLBACK_AGENT_H_V AA 
         INNER JOIN KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO BB ON AA.TIDSPUNKT = BB.DATO 
         RIGHT JOIN KS_DRIFT.SYS_DATE_KS CC ON AA.TIDSPUNKT = CC.THIS_DATE
WHERE    AA.TIDSPUNKT BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-04'
AND      AA.AFSLUTTET_AF = BB.INITIALER
GROUP BY AA.TIDSPUNKT, LAST_UPD, AA.CREATED, AA.LØST_SEKUNDER, 
         AA.AFSLUTTET_AF, AA.AGENTGRUPPE
```

However i get From keyword not found where expected

Comment: I think you need to be more clear in what you explain. Try to be crisp with data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the DATEDIFF function when trying to calculate differences in time.

For example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, THIS_DATE_OPENING, LAST_UPD);
```

Where "ss" denotes seconds.  This first parameter is the datepart that you want to calculate.  Like seconds or minutes or days or whatever.

You can find the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269(v=sql.80).aspx

Let me know if I didn't understand your question correctly.

I also just noticed that you're trying to do this:

```
CASE WHEN AA.CREATED >= CC.THIS_DATE_CLOSING THEN LØST_TIME =(LAST_UPD-CC.THIS_DATE_OPENING) AS LØST_TIME END
```

Try this instead:

```
'L0ST_TIME' = CASE WHEN AA.CREATED >= CC.THIS_DATE_CLOSING THEN DATEDIFF(ss, CC.THIS_DATE_OPENING, LAST_UPD) END
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your response. My problem is just that the seconds of day is a collum that already exist and only if the created date is after the companys closing date then the value should be changed

an example could be: our company closes at 20.00 mondays should the row be created 20.15 then the seconds of day value is not correct and should be changed accordingly

Comment: now i get FROM Keyword not found where expected (see update 2 for my full SQL statement so far)

Comment: I think I didn't understand your initial problem correctly.  It sounds like what you need is a computed column.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx  This should automatically update based on the other fields without your intervention

Comment: isnt it possible to compute a collum within a select statement using if else?

Like so:
DECLARE VALUE INT
if(AA.CREATED >= CC.THIS_DATE_CLOSING THEN value =(AA.LAST_UPD-CC.THIS_DATE_OPENING) ELSE VALUE =(AA.LØST_SEKUNDER)) ?

Comment: You can certainly compute the value and assign it to the variable but then you would need to run an update statement to update the "computed" column.  If you want the column to be updated automatically, then you need a trigger on the table or it needs to be defined in the field itself (computed field).  Maybe you're looking for an update statement and not a select statement?

Comment: i do not wish to update. i need to use the result for my application only could you give me an example of how i would achieve this with an assigned value?

Comment: It looks like you changed one of your field names in the newest version of your query:'LØST_TIME' = CASE WHEN AA.CREATED >= CC.THIS_DATE_CLOSING THEN DATEDIFF(ss, CC.THIS_DATE_OPENING, LAST_UPD) END,
you're using AA.CREATED for the comparison part but using LAST_UPD for the calculation.  Is that intended?  If you only need the derived value then this query should work for you assuming the column names are all correct.  If this still doesn't fix your issue please review your question and make sure you're including all of the details you need to be including.